# Use other template engine in Spring Boot

Tags: template-engine, spring-boot

Spring Boot supports FreeMarker/Groovy/Thymeleaf/Velocity out-of-the-box, how can I switch to other template engines (httl etc.) with no xml configuration?

Do I have to override contentNegotiatingViewResolver and add a list of ViewResolver to it as showed in [this post](https://spring.io/blog/2013/06/03/content-negotiation-using-views) ?

Comment: What template engine do you need to configure?

Comment: like httl, http://httl.github.io/en/

Comment: Interesting! I haven't attempted to add a different view resolver than the ones provided by Spring Boot, but I doubt you need to override `contentNegotiatingViewResolver`. I took a small look at `ThymeleafAutoConfiguration`, `FreemarkerAutoConfiguration` and `VelocityAutoConfiguration` and it looks fairly straight forward to add a different view resolver based on those